# Quelle est la différence entre la chance et le hasard ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Je connais la différence quand j'utilise ces mots mais c'est difficile à expliquer. Est-ce que quelqu'un a une bonne explication ?

Par exemple, on dit « un coup de chance » mais on voit une page « au hasard » sur Wikipédia.

Comment: Les deux mots ont plusieurs acceptions, certaines communes, d'autres pas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Le "hasard" définit des événements ou circonstances qui peuvent survenir et qui peuvent être favorables ou non. On peut voir ça comme un ensemble de possibilités.

Exemple : Laisser cela au hasard.

Une "chance" est une possibilité, une probabilité que quelque chose se produise. C'est souvent connoté comme un événement positif, comme dans "un coup de chance". On peut donc voir un "coup de chance" comme un élément fortement positif dû au "hasard".

Comment: Et quand c'est négatif on parle de risque.

Comment: Très juste mais seulement avant que l'événement ne se produise

Answer (score 10):

Il est souvent intéressant de voir l'histoire d'un mot pour en comprendre ses sens. Peut-être que les deux soient parfois confondus de nos jours vient du fait que « chance » et « hasard » trouvent leur origine dans le jeu.

**Chance** vient du latin *cadentia* une des formes de *cadere* (tomber). La chance c'est d'abord la façon dont tombent les dés, ensuite le mot a été employé pour désigner le sort, le hasard, puis la manière dont les choses se produisent, et dans la langue contemporaine c'est surtout le sens de « sort heureux et favorable » qui prédomine.

**Hasard** vient d'un mot arabe qui désignait un jeu de dés. En vieux français il a d'abord désigné un jeu de dés spécifique puis un coup heureux à ce jeu. Au XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle il a pris le sens de *risque*, *circonstance périlleuse*  (on parle encore des « hasards de la guerre »).
Actuellement il a surtout le sens de concours de circonstances plus ou moins explicables.

« Chance » et « hasard » ont, comme le disait Le Francophone, plusieurs acceptions, parmi ces diverses acceptions on peut en citer quelques unes des plus répandues.

- **Chance** peut désigner actuellement :

  - Une  occasion heureuse :

> Nous avons eu la chance de visiter Paris lors de notre séjour en Europe.

Les  circonstances :

> La chance a tourné et je ne gagne plus rien depuis longtemps.

L'éventualité :

> Il y a des chances que nous ayons de la pluie cette après-midi.

Dans ce sens il se met en général au pluriel.

**Hasard**

- La cause à ce qui peut arriver ou se fait sans raison apparente :

  > Je l'ai rencontré tout à fait par hasard. 
  >   
  >   Je n'avais rien préparé et j'ai parlé au hasard de l'improvisation.
  >   
  >   *Le hasard est l'explication que donnent les humains de ces rencontres imprévues qui ont bouleversé leur existence.*
  >   (citation célèbre d'Edmond Jabès)
- L'idée de quelque chose qui se fait n'importe comment, sans ordre :

  > Je marchais au hasard sans réfléchir.
- Il prend le sens de « en prévision » dans la locution :

  > Je prends mon maillot de bain à tout hasard.
  >   
  >   (c'est à dire au cas où j'en ai besoin)

Les usages entre les deux mots  ne se recoupent pas vraiment.

> 1) C'est par hasard que j'ai trouvé ce livre chez un antiquaire.
>   2) C'est par chance que j'ai trouvé ce livre chez un antiquaire.

Dans 1) j'exprime le fait que je suis rentrée dans la boutique au hasard/ou que je feuilletais les livres sans but défini.
Dans 2) j'exprime la même idée mais en plus je porte un jugement. Pour exprimer la même idée avec « hasard » j'aurais ressenti le besoin de dire « c'est par un heureux hasard que... »

Pour finir cette citation de Balzac trouvée dans le TLF :

> *...j'ai vu, depuis vingt ans, le monde par son envers, dans ses caves, et j'ai reconnu qu'il y a dans la marche des choses une force que vous nommez la providence, que j'appelais le hasard, que mes compagnons appellent la chance.* Balzac, Splendeurs et misères des courtisanes,1847, p. 642.

Comment: Maillot de bain « tout hasard » ou « à tout hasard » ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: J'allais peut-être créer une nouvelle mode !

Answer (score 1):

La chance est un hasard bénéfique

Comment: Des fois, oui, mais pas toujours. Résumer à cela est vraiment trop simplifier.

Comment: @Gilles - J'accepterais volontiers le -1 si vous donnez un exemple pour votre *mais* qui mettrait à mort la formule qui par un heureux hasard m'est venu à l'esprit, pour rédiger une réponse bénéfique.

Comment: Il y en a dans la réponse de Laure.

Comment: @Gilles - L'explication 2) de Laure n'explique-telle pas que *je juge* le hasard *heureux*, donc *bénéfique*, ce qui en logique habituelle retire ce bénéfice au hasard seul face à la chance ? En six mots n'y a-t-il pas l'expression de la nuance que le *je* porte à ce phénomène qui arrive sans explication logique, que j'accepte tel quel (hasard) ou que je valorise (chance) par l'avantage que j'en retire ?

Answer (score 1):

Il n'y a aucune raison pour confondre les mots "*chance*" et "*hasard*", quoiqu'ils appartiennent au même champ de connaissance, car ce serait comme confondre la route et la voiture.

**Le hasard désigne l'ensemble des relations de causalité que la raison ne peut expliquer**, où l'on constate que la même cause apparente peut avoir une variété d'effets distincts: lorsque le croupier lance la roulette, il fait toujours le même geste en apparence, et cependant le numéro qui va sortir est toujours imprévisible pour l'observateur: c'est *l'oeuvre du hasard*. En réalité, on peut considérer que le hasard désigne ***toute causalité dont la complexité ne peut être décelée par l'intelligence humaine***.

**La chance est la possibilité d'apparition d'un événement issu d'une causalité réputée hasardeuse**, par conséquent un événement imprévisible au sens où il est en concurrence avec d'autres événements dont on ne peut savoir *a priori* lequel surviendra: A la roulette, le numéro 7 a ***une chance*** de sortir. Cette chance possède une probabilité d'occurrence qui, si elle peut être calculée, permet à l'observateur de connaître la fréquence théorique à laquelle un événement peut survenir. Dans notre exemple, la chance du numéro 7 a une probabilité de 1/37e: Le joueur peut donc *tenter sa chance*, c'est à dire miser sur un événement dont il connaît la probabilité.

La ***chance*** est donc un concept purement mathématique. Cependant, avec l'usage, le mot "chance" a été dérivé vers ce qui peut en être parfois une conséquence morale: On parle alors de "***bonne chance***" ou de "***malchance***". Ensuite, la "bonne chance" a été remplacée par la "chance", ce qui introduit un sens nouveau, non conforme au sens étymologique.

Cette déformation a fini par produire, chez certains locuteurs, une contestation du bon emploi du mot chance: ainsi, ils croient apporter une précision sémantique lorsqu'ils contestent l'expression **"vous avez une chance sur mille de vous tuer en voiture"** qui est pourtant parfaitement correcte, et croient corriger cette expression en disant "*un risque sur mille*", ce qui est au contraire une faute de langage manifeste: "*une chance sur mille*" est correct, "*un risque sur mille*" ne l'est pas, car cela revient à dévier le sens du mot "risque" en lui attribuant le sens étymologique du mot "chance", ce qui déforme inutilement la langue.

Answer (score 0):

Tout ce que je vais dire n'est que de ma perception. Si je devais établir une différence. Ça serait la volonté.
Le hasard est dépourvue de volonté. Je m'explique par un exemple simple.
Une personne qui trouve un ticket de loto dans la rue et qui gagne, on dira que le hasard fait bien les choses. Il ne s'est pas dit qu'il allait se retrouver gagnant du loto en sortant de son appartement. Cela rejoins d'ailleurs la pluralité d'événements imprévisibles.
La chance pour moi serait plus une personne qui décide de jouer au loto. Il y a une volonté d'avoir de la chance et de gagner. C'est peut être pour cela qu'on dit que la chance se provoque et pas le hasard.
Je pense que l'homme a voulu différencier par le langage la perception des deux situations différentes mais qui amène au même résultat. Je préfère compter donc sur la chance que le hasard. D'ailleurs le terme hasard est plus négatif que le terme chance. Ce n'est sûrement pas dû au hasard. J'espère avoir résumé au mieux ma pensée. Peut être y a-t-il une autre perception.

Answer (score -1):

La chance n’a-t-elle pas la connotation ou n’est-elle pas le résultat d’une action ou une démarche ?

Comment: Bienvenue sur Stack Exchange. FL est [un site de questions-réponses](https://french.stackexchange.com/help), pas un forum de discussion.  Vous pouvez [poser une question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) et quand vous aurez assez de réputation vous pourrez laisser des [commentaires](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/20472)